# Selenium WebDriver Test on a Airways Website

Tags: java

I am new to the Selenium, i am trying a test on airways website, i wanted to see all the airports available in the "FROM TEXT BOX", how can i get that information, i know it is hidden but is their any way to access it. i can pass a "AIRPORT NAME" but i wanted to see what are available airports and then select one. because all the airline does not provide provide service all over the world.if some one could help me, i would be glad.

Comment: Do you have dropdowns of countries , airports?

Comment: When you say it's hidden, do you mean that the airport information doesn't become available until you've chosen something else, or that you don't see it until you've done something? There's a difference: if there's an AJAX call on the website to populate airport information after you've chosen something, then no, you can't get all airports from that page/field.

Comment: No,they do not have any drop down list, @HelpingHands this is the web site i am trying "http://www.cheapoair.com/".

Comment: i don't see any information when i click on the textarea, but i can only pass the values and select them.when i do it manually when i enter a letter then i can see all the list of airports staring with that letter.i am working on "http://www.cheapoair.com/". @KatePaulk

Answer (score 1):

This will be hard to achieve. It's possible to capture the shown contents with Selenium, but **the complete list is stored in a server-side database**.

As soon as you're typing a letter, the suggestions are loaded (with an Ajax call) in the list in this HTML section. The div loses its `hidden` class.

The problem is that you're only getting a **limited** set of airports, based on your input value. There's no way around this.

```
<div class="suggestion-box__content hidden">
    <p class="suggestion-box__msg suggestion-box__error-msg icon ic-warning-empty hidden"></p>
    <ul class="suggestion-box__list"></ul>
    <a href="#" class="suggestion-box__close icon ic-cancel">Close</a>
</div>
```

As soon as a value is selected, the `<ul>` is cleared. So nothing is stored client-side except (momentarily) the suggestions you're shown.

Comment: so it is not possible when Ajax are used to retrieve data, any other mechanism to hide data other than Ajax.i mean how many ways exits to hide the data. @Frederik

Comment: @Nick with Selenium you can only retrieve data that is in the HTML page (hidden or not). As the auto-suggestions loaded in the HTML are only part of the complete airport list, you can never retrieve the entire list in one go.

Comment: You can always use an HTTP Request into the AJAX call yourself and use the list. While this will create the list dynamically, it will not validate the validity of the list itself. If you are testing this site I would find out where this list should be populated from and then validate that the AJAX calls alone contain all of the data from the origin source.

Answer (score 0):

So to get an iterative working list go to the following url

http://intellisuggest.fareportal.com/api/IntelliSuggest/2.0/json/AutoSuggest/AIR%2FALL%2F**a**?callback=jQuery19108656365454662591_1422021006668&_=1422021006672

Changing out the bolded "a" to be the letter/string you would like to get a list of airports that match. This returns in a formatting as follows:

```
jQuery19108656365454662591_1422021006668({"Location":[{"Code":"ATL","Text":"ATL - Atlanta Hartsfield Jackson International Airport, Georgia, United States","Type":"Airport","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"US","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"United States","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"ATL","Text":"ATL - Atlanta All Airports, Georgia, United States","Type":"City","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"US","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"United States","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"AUS","Text":"AUS - Austin Bergstrom, Texas, United States","Type":"Airport","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"US","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"United States","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"AUS","Text":"AUS - Austin All Airports, Texas, United States","Type":"City","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"US","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"United States","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"ABQ","Text":"ABQ - Albuquerque, New Mexico, United States","Type":"Airport","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"US","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"United States","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"ANC","Text":"ANC - Anchorage, Alaska, United States","Type":"Airport","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"US","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"United States","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"ANC","Text":"ANC - Anchorage All Airports, Alaska, United States","Type":"City","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"US","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"United States","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"AMS","Text":"AMS - Amsterdam, Netherlands","Type":"Airport","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"NL","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"Netherlands","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"ALB","Text":"ALB - Albany, New York, United States","Type":"Airport","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"US","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"United States","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"ALB","Text":"ALB - Albany All Airports, New York, United States","Type":"City","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"US","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"United States","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"ATH","Text":"ATH - Athens, Greece","Type":"Airport","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"GR","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"Greece","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"ATH","Text":"ATH - Athens All Airports, Greece","Type":"City","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"GR","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"Greece","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"AUA","Text":"AUA - Aruba, Aruba","Type":"Airport","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"AW","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"Aruba","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"AMM","Text":"AMM - Amman, Jordan","Type":"Airport","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"JO","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"Jordan","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"AMM","Text":"AMM - Amman All Airports, Jordan","Type":"City","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"JO","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"Jordan","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"ABE","Text":"ABE - Allentown Bethlehem, Pennsylvania, United States","Type":"Airport","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"US","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"United States","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"ACY","Text":"ACY - Atlantic City, New Jersey, United States","Type":"Airport","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"US","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"United States","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"AKL","Text":"AKL - Auckland, New Zealand","Type":"Airport","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"NZ","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"New Zealand","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"AKL","Text":"AKL - Auckland All Airports, New Zealand","Type":"City","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"NZ","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"New Zealand","MisspellMatchWord":""},{"Code":"AMD","Text":"AMD - Ahmedabad, India","Type":"Airport","Source":"AIR_LOCATIONS","HotelLocationID":"","IATACode":"","Distance":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"CountoryCode":"IN","SubType":"","SubText":"","CountoryName":"India","MisspellMatchWord":""}],"Errors":null})
```

All of that being said ......

***What are you attempting to accomplish***

If you are testing the site you likely do not need to validate every single airport comes up on the page. Validating the data from the AJAX level will be far simpler than from the page level, plus give you an easily repeatable and responsive data.

Following that, you would need to validate that the Webpage displays data from the AJAX call and that the data is correct, which will only require a few of the different AJAX calls and not require all of the data to be verified.

In essence, if you are tasked with testing this site, validate the data at the API level. It will save you the hassle of making tons of different Web calls.